# casting int to bool in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, implicit-conversion

I'm having a list of different types of values exported from JSON.

```
class StudentDetailsToMarkAttendance {
  int att_on_off_status;
  String name;
  String reg_number;
  int status;

  StudentDetailsToMarkAttendance(
      {this.att_on_off_status, this.name, this.reg_number, this.status});

  factory StudentDetailsToMarkAttendance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return StudentDetailsToMarkAttendance(
      att_on_off_status: json['att_on_off_status'],
      name: json['name'],
      reg_number: json['reg_number'],
      status: json['status'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['att_on_off_status'] = this.att_on_off_status;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['reg_number'] = this.reg_number;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I am trying to use the value of **status** as the value parameter of `Checkbox`. I am trying to parse `int` to `String` like this.

```
value:((widget.studentDetailsList[index].status = (1 ? true : false) as int)as bool)
```

but there seems to be a problem with this conversion. I am not getting exact way of converting `int` to `bool` in dart.  It says

> Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.

Answer (score 25):

To convert **int to bool** in Dart, you can use ternary operator :

```
myInt == 0 ? false : true;
```

To convert **bool to int** in Dart, you can use ternary operator :

```
myBool ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Shorter answers for **int to bool**: `myInt == 1`

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I think this is a clean way to convert from `int` to `bool`:

```dart
myBool = myInt.isOdd;
```

Or with null safety

```dart
myBool = myInt?.isOdd ?? false;
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to automatically "convert" an integer to a boolean.

Dart objects have a type, and converting them to a different type would mean changing which object they are, and that's something the language have chosen not to do for you.

The condition needs to be a boolean, and an integer is-not a boolean.

Dart has very few ways to do implicit conversion between things of different type. The only real example is converting a callable object to a function (by tearing off the `call` method), which is done implicitly if the context requires a function.
(Arguably an integer *literal* in a double context is "converted to double", but there is never an integer *value* there. It's *parsed* as a double.)

So, if you have an integer and want a bool, you need to write the conversion yourself.
Let's assume you want zero to be false and non-zero to be true. Then all you have to do is write `myInteger != 0`, or in this case:

```dart
value: widget.studentDetailsList[index].status != 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a getter.

```
bool get status {
    if(widget.studentDetailsList[index].status == 0)
              return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then pass status to value.

```
value: status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
value: widget.studentDetailsList[index].status == 1
```

Comment: `? true : false` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I've just published a lib to convert any object to a `bool` value in dart, [asbool](https://pub.dev/packages/asbool) (Disclaimer: I'm the author)

For `int` objects you can use it as a extension (`.asBool`) or helper method (`asBool(obj)`):

```dart
int? num = 23;
int? num2;

assert(num.asBool == true); // true == true
assert(asBool(num) == true); // true == true
assert(num2.asBool == false); // false == false
assert(0.asBool == asBool(null)); // false == false
assert(120.asBool == asBool(2.567)); // false == false
```

It also works for whatever other object like Strings, Iterables, Maps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this often, you can go with creating an extension:

```
extension BoolExtensions on bool {
  int toInt() {
    return this ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

Then it can be used as:

```
boolVal.toInt()
```